# Ruby on Rails application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion, startup-error

I'm trying to deploy some changes, and I just cannot see them as the URL I got sends me on a Phusion error page "Ruby on Rails application could not be started".

When I check the logs, I get something like this:

```
Exception ArgumentError in PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner (syntax error on line 36, col 1: ` sdc_id: dcsvdln1l00000kv1qsmc4oob_1p3v')
```

I have absolutely no idea about what's going on, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Rolf

P.S.: the whole trace

```
Exception ArgumentError in PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner (syntax error on line 36, col 1: ` sdc_id: dcsvdln1l00000kv1qsmc4oob_1p3v') (process 28735):
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
    from /home/..../config/environment.rb:92
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:303:in `preload_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:252:in `initialize_server'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:254:in `report_app_init_status'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:237:in `initialize_server'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:194:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:213:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:262:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:256:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:255:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:154:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/bin/passenger-spawn-server:61
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more info it looks like you have an error in a yaml file somewhere. Perhaps there was a conflict that didn't get resolved? Do a grep on sdc_id and see what you see.

Comment: I added the exception stack trace to the first post

Comment: Yeah, you can see your environment.rb is loading up a yaml file. Just look in your config folder, I'll bet there's something wanky in there.

Comment: raw_config = File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "/config/config.yml") 

APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(raw_config)[RAILS_ENV]

The last line with APP_CONFIG seems to be the cause, although it works fine with other projects with the exact same file... I'm really clueless :(

Comment: there was indeed an extra line that is from nowhere in config.yml :'(